# Python - Delete line by first character

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I have a 'test.txt' file that contains:

```
(5 rows)
a
(7 rows)
b
```

and i wanna delete the line if the line starts with the '(' character.
My code is here:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('('):
                fout.write(line.replace('(',''))
            else:
                fout.write(line)
```

but returns:

```
5 rows)
a
7 rows)
b
```

I'd like to get the result:

```
a

b
```

Is it possible with 'starts.with'?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want an empty row as a result if the source line starts with a `(` or no line at all?

Comment: Just write a new line instead of replacing the found `(`, i.e. `fout.write("\n")`)

Comment: yes Matthias...

Comment: If the line starts with `(`, why are you writing it out? Just write an newline (`\n`) inside your `if` block and you should be good.

Comment: If you want to write nothing, just say "if not line.startswith('('):" and don't include an else clause.

Answer (score 1):

You replace a character and also write the line.

Instead of the, you do `fout.write('\n')` which writes a newline

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('('):
                fout.write('\n')
            else:
                fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change what you do in the cases where the line *does* start with a `(`. All we want to do is just `write` a newline (`\n`). We do not want to `replace` anything as we want to get rid of the line entirely.

So, here is what the completed code would look like:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('('):
                fout.write("\n")
            else:
                fout.write(line)
```

which creates `result.txt` as:

```
[empty line]
a
[empty line]
b
```

*where `[empty line]` represents just a blank line but makes it more obvious in this answer*

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired output using following steps

- Open your desired file in `read` mode
- Read all lines
- Close file
- Open file again in `write` mode
- Write desired lines, replace undesired with `\n`
- Close file

  ```
  f = open("test.txt","r")
  lines = f.readlines()
  f.close()

  f = open("test.txt","w")

  for line in lines:
     if not line.startswith('('):
        f.write(line)
     else:
         f.write('\n')

  f.close()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

One can also use system commands to work on files. For example in Linux:

```
import os
os.system("cat test.txt | sed 's/^(.*$//' > results.txt")
```

`cat` reads out the infile, `|` is to pipe the output to `sed` which replaces lines starting with `(` to blank and finally `>` redirects output to outfile.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using "not":

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if not line.startswith('('):
                fout.write(line + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want with the `.startswith()` method.  Your check is fine. It's what you do when you find the match that is causing your troubles.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('('):
                fout.write('\n') # fout.write(line.replace('(',''))
            else:
                fout.write(line)
```

If you want to get rid of the lines that start with '(', just don't write them out to the new file... Write out a blank line (just new line character) instead.  Replacing lines that begin with a '(' with blank lines seems to be what you want based on your description above.

If you don't want to replace the '(' lines with blank lines, then your code can be a little simpler:

```
            if line.startswith('('):
                fout.write('\n') # fout.write(line.replace('(',''))
            else:
                fout.write(line)
```

can just be

```
            if not line.startswith('('):
                fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fout.write(line.replace('(',''))` just use:

`fout.write('\n')` which will replace that line with a new line character, so you code would be:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('('):
                fout.write('\n')
            else:
                fout.write(line)
```